# printer settings for FreeRDP

Tags: remote-desktop

I am using FreeRDP to get connected to our company Windows Server.
Now i want to redirect my printer. Therefore i have to put some info in the syntax I use for the connection.

`/printer:<device>,<driver>`

Where in Ubuntu can get the info , of my local printer?

Comment: How is your local printer connected?